# Reference to home not working in Nautilus Action-Config-Tool

Tags: paths, nautilus-actions

[image: Screenshot of the Field]

The path field (In the given Screenshot) is given the input: ~/.subseeker/subseeker.py, but it's not working, the code isn't executing when the command runs.

[image]

I even tried- `$HOME/.subseeker/subseeker.py`

With no luck,

But when I give an absolute path, It works fine and dandy!

But i really need to make it independent of the username.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try `/home/$USER/.subseeker/subseeker.py`

Comment: No luck with that , either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue. See the image below, I configured the tool to "Display Output", in that way you can see any error message in an easier way.

When using absolute path, you get something like this:
[image]

What you're trying is very similar to this, here you can see the error:
[image]

And when using $HOME variable but with `python` command at the beginning, it works perfectly.
[image]

My python script just prints "It works".

Hope it helps to solve your issue.

Comment: I had to switch the execution mode to **"Display output"**, Only then it worked!

Comment: Nice, good to hear that it worked! :)

Comment: how did you replicate my problem? I mean, did you go to GitHub to download the source code?

Answer (score 1):

It is not referenced as being possible to give a non-absolute path (expect from `$PATH` itself).

What you can do is add a script (placed in `PATH`) that will run the given file (gave as a parameter) according to the home directory of the user.

Just open a terminal and type

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/run-in-home
```

then simply write this :

```
#!/bin/bash

`$HOME/$1`
```

exit the editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and give execution permission to this script

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/run-in-home
```

Now you can set the `Path :`  field to `run-in-home` and the `Parameters :` field to `'path/to/file param1 parm2'` so that, in your case, it would be

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to launch your file with another program (for example a .jar file, or if python cannot be run directly), you can change `/usr/bin/run-in-home` to this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
        `$1 $HOME/$2`
else
        `$HOME/$1`
fi
```

and now the `Parameters  :` field becomes `'program program-parameter1 program-parameter2' 'path/to/file param1 parm2'`, for instance `'java -jar' 'Documents/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar'`.